# Прозрачность в BitMap

Tags: delphi

Как сделать некоторые части BitMap прозрачными? BitMap.Transparent не помогает

Comment: Если Вам нужно сделать некоторые части Image прозрачными, то поставьте у него свойство Transparent True, чвет прозрачности определяется чветом левого нижнего пиксела (насколько я помню).

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap вообще прозрачным не бывает. Св-во Transparent лишь даёт программе возможность отображать не всю картинку, а только её часть. Если нужны прозрачные и полупрозрачные картинки можно использовать png, но никак не bmp.

Comment: gif ещё с прозрачностью. Древние IE прозрачность в png не понимали. Правда давно это было

Comment: Ну, за использование gif в программах вроде платить надо...?

Comment: Не знаю. Вполне возможно

Comment: Брежнева еще вспомните :-) На LZW патенты истекли 8 лет назад :-)

Answer (score 0):

Это смотря какой цвет должен считаться прозрачным.
Если, например, белый, то так:

```
bitmap.Transparent:=true;
bitmap.Transparent:=rgb(255,255,255); // белый цвет
```

Comment: Говорю же, не работает

Comment: А bitmap выводится в TImage ?

Comment: Нет, сохраняется в файл